# XQuery : call to undeclared function?

Tags: xml, function, xquery

I have the following issue: I wrote a function in my .xqy file, but when I try to call it, I get the error:

> Call to undeclared function: local:getStr

That's simply what I'm doing:

```
declare function local:getStr($str as xs:string) as xs:string{
...
};
return
...
<td>{local:getStr($var)}</td>
```

Comment: Do you rebind the `local` prefix in your constructed XML? This would affect function resolution.

Comment: Why do you have a return in the example? Does not make much sense there. Better post the entire source. Or remove stuff, to get a minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your example is complete except for the ellipses, your problem would appear to be that you never bind any namespace to the prefix `local`.  You will need to add something like

```
declare namespace local = "http://localhost/nss";
```

in the prolog of your XQuery module.  If that's the problem, then the error message is not the most informative one I've ever seen in my life.

(If you do have a namespace declaration in your code, but elided it as irrelevant for the problem, then I suggest finding the shortest example you can manage that will replicate your problem, and adding it to the question.)

Comment: The prefix `local` is required to be bound by the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-basics):

"Certain namespace prefixes are predeclared by XQuery and bound to fixed namespace URIs. These namespace prefixes are as follows:
...
 `local = http://www.w3.org/2005/xquery-local-functions` (see 4.15 Function Declaration.)"

Comment: EDIT : it works now. Don't really know what was the problem but... thank you.

Comment: @LeoWörteler: you caught me out to lunch on that one -- I had never noticed that.  Thank you for teaching me.